# Composite video signal detection problem?

Tags: signal, camera, video, detection

I have an android headunit and I installed a reversing camera to it.

The problem is that the headunit does not seem to detect the camera signal if the environment is too bright. It just shows black screen until I block the camera lens momentarily with my finger and release.

I think, it did not have this problem when I tried the camera with my monitor (which also has composite input). Also the picture quality was much better. But it is also possible that it was not bright enough inside. I have to re-check that.

I do not have access to oscilloscope but I checked the output voltage of the camera when NOT connected to headunit and it was about 1.5v DC. Another camera was showing about 0.7v DC. Not sure why there is so big difference between cameras. Any ideas?

I do not know how the headunit checks the existance of composite signal  or why the quality is worse when camera is used with the headunit. But I would like to fix this problem. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Perhaps I need to attenuate the signal?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that DC or AC voltage you measured? From camera when it is connected or not connected to head unit? But different cameras have different output stages, signal amplitude can be different and the DC bias voltage can be different. Some devices just work better together than some others. Signal quality might differ too, there might be interference so it can be too noisy to lock on. Monochrome video showing peak white should be 1 Vpp, composite color can make it near 1.3 to 1.4 Vpp.

Comment: One possible reason for that 0.7V vs 1.5V difference - The unconnected camera output probably was unterminated.  A "proper" composit video signal has a 75 ohm output impedance and expects a 75 ohm termination.  Those two impedances form a 2:1 divider, so it is not a big surprise that whatever the meter is reading changes by about 2:1 when it goes from unconnected to connected.

Comment: _"Perhaps I need to attenuate the signal?"_ - perhaps. Try connecting a 75~150 Ohm resistor across the output.

Comment: @AnalogKid the difference was between 2 different cameras both unconnected. I was just wondering why one camera output shows higher DC voltage in the meter and if it can be related.